# Use variadic args to call subsequent method

Tags: c++17, variadic-templates

Assume I have function that accept 1 callable F and variadic list of arguments:

```
template <class F, class ...Args>
void combine(F& f, Args&& ... args)
```

`F` may have any number of arguments from 1 to `sizeof...(Args)`. So I need using c++17 to invoke `F` and after that just put not used args to `std::cout` like that

```
{
    std::invoke(f, [some way to restrict args]);
    std::cout << [The rest of args] << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Not possible in general. `F` could e.g. be a class with multiple overloads of `operator()`, taking different numbers of arguments. Or an `operator()` that's itself a variadic template. It should be possible to do something like "find the longest prefix of `args...` that `f` is callable with".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The great problem is detect the number of arguments of `F`.

As pointed by Igor Tandetnik in a comment, this isn't possible in general, because the `f` func can be variadic, of a lambda with a template `operator()`, or a instance of a class/struct with multiple `operator()`.

Anyway... in some cases you can detect the number of the arguments with something as follows

```
template <typename T>
struct num_args 
   : public num_args<decltype(&T::operator())>
 { };
 
template <typename R, typename ... Args>
struct num_args<R(*)(Args...)>
   : public std::integral_constant<std::size_t, sizeof...(Args)>
 { };

// other specialization follows
```

At this point, you can write `combine()` to call an helper function with an appropriate couple of indexes and a tuple of arguments

```
template <typename F, typename ... Args>
void combine (F & func, Args && ... as)
 { 
   constexpr auto n1 { num_args<F>::value };
   constexpr auto n2 { sizeof...(Args) - n1 };

   combine_helper(std::make_index_sequence<n1>{},
                  std::make_index_sequence<n2>{},
                  func,
                  std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(as)...));
 }
```

and the helper function can be simply as follows

```
template <std::size_t ... Is1, std::size_t ... Is2, typename F, typename T>
void combine_helper (std::index_sequence<Is1...>,
                     std::index_sequence<Is2...>,
                     F & func, T && t)
 {
   func(std::get<Is1>(std::forward<T>(t))...);
   (std::cout << ... << std::get<sizeof...(Is1)+Is2>(std::forward<T>(t)))
      << '\n';
 }
```

The following is a full compiling C++17 example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>

template <typename T>
struct num_args 
   : public num_args<decltype(&T::operator())>
 { };
 
template <typename R, typename ... Args>
struct num_args<R(*)(Args...)>
   : public std::integral_constant<std::size_t, sizeof...(Args)>
 { };

template <typename R, typename ... Args>
struct num_args<R(Args...)>
   : public std::integral_constant<std::size_t, sizeof...(Args)>
 { };

template <typename R, typename C, typename ... Args>
struct num_args<R(C::*)(Args...)>
   : public std::integral_constant<std::size_t, sizeof...(Args)>
 { };

template <typename R, typename C, typename ... Args>
struct num_args<R(C::*)(Args...) const>
   : public std::integral_constant<std::size_t, sizeof...(Args)>
 { };

template <std::size_t ... Is1, std::size_t ... Is2, typename F, typename T>
void combine_helper (std::index_sequence<Is1...>,
                     std::index_sequence<Is2...>,
                     F & func, T && t)
 {
   func(std::get<Is1>(std::forward<T>(t))...);
   (std::cout << ... << std::get<sizeof...(Is1)+Is2>(std::forward<T>(t)))
      << '\n';
 }

template <typename F, typename ... Args>
void combine (F & func, Args && ... as)
 { 
   constexpr auto n1 { num_args<F>::value };
   constexpr auto n2 { sizeof...(Args) - n1 };

   combine_helper(std::make_index_sequence<n1>{},
                  std::make_index_sequence<n2>{},
                  func,
                  std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(as)...));
 }


void func_1 (int a, int b, int c)
 { std::cout << "the product is: " << a*b*c << '\n'; }

int main()
 {
   auto extra  { 100 };
   auto func_2 { [&](int a, int b, int c, int d)
    { std::cout << "the extra sum is: " << extra+a+b+c+d << '\n'; } };

   combine(func_1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
   combine(func_2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
 }
```